# How can I ease the work of getting pixel coordinates from a spritesheet?

Tags: sprites, tools, spritesheet

When it comes to spritesheets they're usually easier to use, and they're very efficient memory-wise, but the problem that I'm always having is getting the actual position of a sprite from a sheet. Usually, I have to throw in some aproximated values and modify them several times until I get it right.

My question: is there a tool which can basically show you the coordinates of the mouse relative to the image you have opened? Or is there a simpler method of getting the exact rectangle that the sprite is contained in?

Comment: I'm not sure if i got you right but you can easily get this information by knowing the number of sprites in your sheet and the size of them (and maybe the amount of sprites per line).

Comment: That usually applies however in my case my spritesheet consists of texts with post-effects of various sizes, width and height, besides, it's hard to actually remember all those numbers

Comment: ho ok, maybe you should include the type of spritesheet you are using in your question.

Comment: Use a program like http://spritesheetpacker.codeplex.com/ and utilise the output text file to read where your sprites are placed in the image.

Comment: @JonathanConnell Yeah, this is what I meant, good link. - wait maybe not, I think he wants to find the x, y for each frame, not pack separate frames into a sheet.

Comment: @Arthur Wulf White And the only reasonable way to do that is to use a sprite sheet tool that allows you to get the coords, or make your own sprite sheet tool that does the same thing.

Comment: @JonathanConnell - What I meant is does this tool allow to extract the (x,y,width,height) for frames in a existing spritesheet or just pack frames together? If it does not, I may take the time and upload a tool I wrote for that purpose.

Comment: @Arthur Wulf White I would be interested to see that tool, what kind of algorithms do you use?

Comment: If you're programming in XNA, then Visual Studio does this for you. Just open the spritesheet in VS, and it'll show the coordinates of the mouse cursor in the lower right.

Comment: @JonathanConnell Nah, it is a manual tool. I do not presume to know the x,y of each frame. I just allow the user to click and manually select the frames, zoom in for precision and undo the selection if there is a mistake and save the result into a text file. Marton - but it probably does not show the width and height, so you still need to do it in the 'slower' manual way.

Comment: Or just use an intelligent tool to do the work for you, we're programmers after all, that's what we do.

Comment: @JonathanConnell - the problem I found is that sometimes only the programmer / graphics artist knows what is the correct x,y - for instance if the character is ducking, should the xy be lower now? If it is jumping and doing a Contra style somersault where should the frame be positioned? These things are very relevant in vs. fighting games. Sometimes you need to do it manually. (I meant a front flip like this) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SozYg3ZXKM&feature=relmfu

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite I agree but in this case rather than doing it manually you make sure that the frames are the right size and the artist does his job correctly. Doing something manually is time consuming, resource critical and prone to error. The idea is to find solutions so that we don't have to do any boring work manually.

Comment: I guess I can write that, it may require slight adjustments in case the frames are not aligned properly in the spritesheet and there may be issues if the frame is consisted of two separate parts (for instance a basket ball player dribbling a basketball) where the ball does not touch the player.

Comment: The linked spritesheetpacker application already does everything the OP needs.

Comment: @JustinSkiles Care to explain how it accomplishes that? The OP says the issue is "finding the frames in an existing" sheet. Mentions nothing about building a new sheet from its frames.

Comment: There is a tool you can use to do it manually that is relatively painless: 

http://tech-tutors.net/downloads/

And there is a tutorial here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smOtRuxoIs8

Answer (score 4):

There are tools for creating spritesheets from individual images that will also output a meta-data file describing where each image is placed in the spritesheet.

For example you could use [Texture Atlas Generator](http://www.gogo-robot.com/2010/03/20/texture-atlas-sprite-sheet-generator/) to create the spritesheets. In [this blog post](http://blog.pixelpracht.net/?p=306) I show how you'd work with the output to get animations playing in Flash quite effortlessly.

Even if Flash is not your language of choice you might still be able to use a similar approach.

Comment: Yes or use http://spritesheetpacker.codeplex.com !

Comment: I guess he could cut parts of the spritesheet and save them to separate images and then use a tool like this. Does not mean it will make things much easier.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Photoshop, you can use this method.

1. Set units to pixels. *Edit → Preferences → Units and Rulers*.
2. Open the *Info* tab to see the current mouse position.

[image: photoshop info tab]

You can also draw a *Rectangle Marque* selection around your sprite and see it's width and height in the *Info* tab.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool you can use to do it manually that is relatively painless:

http://tech-tutors.net/downloads/

And there is a tutorial here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smOtRuxoIs8

I can share something automated on github if people are interested, the main catch is that if the frames are not even in size which is common, you may need to adjust them manually anyway.

What normally happens when I work with sprites is that the frames are put into an even grid for ease of use. Then every sprite depending on the frame size is in `(j * FRAME_WIDTH, i * FRAME_HEIGHT);`.
If that is not the case cause the artist is not aware of programming needs, I cook up a tool that displays the sprite sheet on screen and saves my click's `(mouseX, mouseY)` positions into a file. I then use that file to split the spritesheet.

I can elaborate on how to create a tool like this or you could use Ivan's advice.

If you do go with making a tool, you may want to both save the first click (for frame's top-left corner, and another click in the bottom-right to get the width and height).

I personally prefer the grid method, have your artist or friend cut and paste the frames into an even grid made of sufficiently large blocks. It would save you time if you have several sprites. Otherwise if there are many spritesheets and they are not in an even grid, you may want to cook up a tool or look for one online(I am not aware of any). They are not difficult to make.

I can upload the source for the tool I use myself to a github for you to download. It saves the results into a text file organize by a list of four values for each frame.

example:

x, y, width, height, x2, y2, width2, height2, ... ,xn, yn, widthn, heightn

You will have to sort (in the code which frame is which) to use the animation correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I am not late here

You can use a [tool like this](https://getspritexy.netlify.app/) and get background positions of the icons in the sprite.

You need to first upload your image, then select an icon from the sprite. CSS will be generated, just copy the generated CSS and use it in your class.

Other options are

1. You need to open the image in an image editor like Photoshop. From there you can find the X and Y position anywhere in the image. Please note that left, top is 0,0. Get the x and y position and use like this

   background-position: -310px -123px;

Please note the "-" sign before X and Y co-ordinates.

2. Start with

   background-position: 1px 1px;

Use Firebug (a firefox extension)to modify  the values on the fly. By trial and error method you can find exact position.